# R data.table fast add with binom.test

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to run `binom.test` on a `data.table` with both the X and N values provided for each row. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475814/faster-looped-binom-test) post, which uses a static N value and tried to modify, but if I try I get:

```
dt = data.table(X=rbinom(100, 625, 1/5), N=rbinom(100, 625, 4/5))
dt[, P := binom.test(x=X, n=N)$p.value ]
# Error in binom.test(x = X, n = N) : incorrect length of 'x'
```

The post also mentions aggregating `by=X`, but even still I get:

```
dt[, P := binom.test(x=X, n=N)$p.value, by=X ]
# Error in binom.test(x = X, n = N) : 'n' must be a positive integer >= 'x'
```

Despite N always being a positive integer greater than X. My goal is not to group by values of X though, I want a binom.test p-value for every row.

Comment: how many rows of data does your actual dataset has?

Comment: It ranges from 50k to over 10 million, depending on the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could group by every row and apply `binom.test` on it.

```
library(data.table)

dt[, P := binom.test(x=X, n=N)$p.value, seq_len(nrow(dt))]
#which is same as
#dt[, P := binom.test(x=X, n=N)$p.value, 1:nrow(dt)]
```

Comment: Do you have a good link to explain why data.table requires the group by operation to do the row operations? I couldn't find anything at rdatatable.gitlab.io

Comment: @dragon951 As we want `p.value` for every row here, we group them by row. I am not aware if this use case is explained anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Map` to loop over each of the corresponding elements of 'X' and 'N'

```
library(data.table)
dt[,  P := unlist(Map(function(x, y) binom.test(x = x, n = y)$p.value,  X, N))]
head(dt)
#     X   N            P
#1: 104 510 3.737474e-43
#2: 137 501 8.640380e-25
#3: 140 517 3.982312e-26
#4: 131 498 6.476382e-27
#5: 114 506 1.000591e-36
#6: 120 507 8.940756e-34
```

---

Or without anonymous function call

```
dt[, P := sapply(Map(binom.test, x = X, n = N), `[[`, "p.value")]
```